# How to use a php variable outside loop which is defined in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I know such questions are previously answered and I applied all the possible solutions. I defined all the variables before the foreach loop but still, it's not working. Here My code:

```
$settings_table = $wpdb->prefix."wpsp_settings";
$sel_setting = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $settings_table");
$school_name = "";
$school_logo = "";
$school_add = "";
$school_city = "";
$school_state = "";
$school_country = "";
$school_number = "";
$school_email = "";
$school_site = "";
foreach( $sel_setting as $setting ) :
  ($setting->id == 1) ? $school_name = $setting->option_value : $school_name = "";
  ($setting->id == 2) ? $school_logo = $setting->option_value : $school_logo = "";
  ($setting->id == 6) ? $school_add = $setting->option_value : $school_add = "";
  ($setting->id == 7) ? $school_city = $setting->option_value : $school_city = "";
  ($setting->id == 8) ? $school_state = $setting->option_value : $school_state = "";
  ($setting->id == 9) ? $school_country = $setting->option_value : $school_country = "";
  ($setting->id == 10) ? $school_number = $setting->option_value : $school_number = "";
  ($setting->id == 12) ? $school_email = $setting->option_value : $school_email = "";
  ($setting->id == 13) ? $school_site = $setting->option_value : $school_site = "";
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? Your `$sel_setting` get all the data you need?

Comment: You don't need the `: $school_name = ""` type code on each line as you already set them to blank before the loop.  They will in fact reset the values each time.

Comment: I'm trying to access variable outside the body of foreach loop. I'm not getting any error message. it simply do not displaying the value of the variable

Comment: You say 'displaying the value of the variable' - which variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the values each time round the loop, as for each item you'r saying...

```
  ($setting->id == 1) ? $school_name = $setting->option_value : $school_name = "";
```

As this loop has different values for $setting->id, this will reset all of the values which don't match.

You would be better off with a `switch... case...` structure...

```
foreach( $sel_setting as $setting ) {
    switch ($setting->id)   {
        case (1):
            $school_name = $setting->option_value;
            break;
        case (2):
            $school_logo = $setting->option_value;
            break;
        // Same for all the others.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't have sens:

```
foreach( $sel_setting as $setting ) :
  ($setting->id == 1) ? $school_name = $setting->option_value : $school_name = "";
  ($setting->id == 2) ? $school_logo = $setting->option_value : $school_logo = "";
  ($setting->id == 6) ? $school_add = $setting->option_value : $school_add = "";
  ($setting->id == 7) ? $school_city = $setting->option_value : $school_city = "";
  ($setting->id == 8) ? $school_state = $setting->option_value : $school_state = "";
  ($setting->id == 9) ? $school_country = $setting->option_value : $school_country = "";
  ($setting->id == 10) ? $school_number = $setting->option_value : $school_number = "";
  ($setting->id == 12) ? $school_email = $setting->option_value : $school_email = "";
  ($setting->id == 13) ? $school_site = $setting->option_value : $school_site = "";
endforeach;
```

for example if $setting->id == 5, you set all variables to blank string OR if you $setting->id == 1 you set $school_name to option_value BUT in the same time set all other variables to blank string.

Simple solution is to use switch / case statement like below:

```
foreach( $sel_setting as $setting ) {
  switch ($setting->id) {
    case 1:
      $school_name = $setting->option_value;
      break;
    case 2:
      $school_logo = $setting->option_value;
      break;
    ...
    case 13:
      $school_site = $setting->option_value;
      break;
  }
}
```